# Onedrive Api search request always returns an empty collection

Tags: rest, onedrive

According to the Onedrive docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search) when a search query is made, it should only return an empty collection if there were no items found. I know that there are items that exist that should show up in the response, however, no matter what I search for, there are no results.

Here is the request I am making:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root/search(q='folder')
```

I have made sure that my request has the correct authorization header, am making a GET request, and that "{user-id}" is correct. At the root of OneDrive, there exists a driveitem with the name 'folder'. After searching for folder, I would expect my GET to come back with my driveitem object, however I only retrieve this empty collection:

```
{
"@odata.context": 
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
"value": []
}
```

Any ideas?